# Adding firebase to project has caused errors in Xcode project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, firebase

I have just tried to add firebase into my project and has caused the error:

```
Ld /Users/Michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Naked_Mole-apueexlqjkdhwcfgdmwnzzwlyyuv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Naked\ MoleTests.xctest/Naked\ MoleTests normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/Michael/Desktop/1twenty/Naked Mole"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.2
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk -L/Users/Michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Naked_Mole-apueexlqjkdhwcfgdmwnzzwlyyuv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Naked_Mole-apueexlqjkdhwcfgdmwnzzwlyyuv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Users/Michael/Desktop/1twenty/Naked\ Mole -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/Michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Naked_Mole-apueexlqjkdhwcfgdmwnzzwlyyuv/Build/Intermediates/Naked\ Mole.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Naked\ MoleTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Naked\ MoleTests.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -bundle_loader /Users/Michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Naked_Mole-apueexlqjkdhwcfgdmwnzzwlyyuv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Naked\ Mole.app/Naked\ Mole -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework XCTest -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/Michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Naked_Mole-apueexlqjkdhwcfgdmwnzzwlyyuv/Build/Intermediates/Naked\ Mole.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Naked\ MoleTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Naked_MoleTests.swiftmodule -mios-simulator-version-min=8.2 -framework Firebase\ 3 -framework FacebookSDK -framework Parse -framework ParseFacebookUtils -framework Bolts -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Naked_Mole-apueexlqjkdhwcfgdmwnzzwlyyuv/Build/Intermediates/Naked\ Mole.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Naked\ MoleTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Naked\ MoleTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Naked_Mole-apueexlqjkdhwcfgdmwnzzwlyyuv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Naked\ MoleTests.xctest/Naked\ MoleTests

ld: framework not found Firebase 3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have followed the instructions exactly by adding all the frameworks required and adding the `-ObjC` into my "other linker flags". I also tried starting a new project and adding it all in there I still come back to the same problem.

It's saying the firebase 3 framework is not found although I have added it to my project?

Comment: It may be because you deleted the file or moved it. I remember getting a simular error when I did not select 'Copy if needed' and deleted the file.